# JavaScript equivalent to Java's ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay

Tags: java, javascript

Is there javascript library out there that provides the concept of scheduled execution of tasks?

An "update function" for example. I want to run it every 60 seconds but I need to make sure that only one instance of the update function is running.

I started with setInterval() but it doesn't suit my needs. I went on with a "promised" while loop but it's hard to understand for an intermediate programmer.

Comment: *but I need to make sure that only one instance of the update function is running* well what should happen in that case? `setInterval` will work, but expect those calls to be queued. If those calls should happen 60 seconds after the last call finishes, use `setTimeout`

Comment: _"I started with `setInterval()` but it doesn't suit my needs."_ Why not?

Comment: In my understanding setInterval() gives you no guarantee about in which order functions return when several functions are invoked. I assume this could result in a 'lost update' bug.